# Check mongodb status before executeQuery()

Tags: php, mongodb

I may have a simple problem but I don't know how to resolve it.
I'm using mongoDB for PHP, and every time I go to a webpage where I have a query on mongoDB, this error show up (silex error) :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

But no log in `error.log` of `apache`. It only happen when my mongodb status is like this :

> ● mongodb.service [...] Active: inactive (dead)

When I start mongoDB with a `mongod` everything work.

I would like to be able to handle this possible problem. Like a `try` (already tried but no effect) on this line :

```
$cursor = $mongo->executeQuery('books.authors', $query);
```

---

**Question :** How can I handle error if mongodb is inactive or not started ?

Comment: `$mongo->executeQuery()` actually tells me you are using the wrong driver. You actually want [PHPLIB](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php) for your "userland" application. You have instead the "lower level" PHPDriver which is not intended for general application usage, but is rather a foundation to build higher level abstractions in the "userland" space. See The [Overview on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php) for a bit more of a visual representation. And download and use the correct driver of course.

Comment: Thanks. It has always been complicated to find what extension or driver use with mongoDB and PHP .. But will it handle this problem ? Because for the moment this `wrong driver` work pretty well for what I need. Is it really a nice to upgrade to go on this driver ?

Comment: What you are going to find is that "works well" becomes far more confusing the more in depth you go. The big hint though is if you look through general documentation you will see methods like `.find()` and `.update()` and `.findOneAndUpdate()`. These are absent from the lower level driver, and of course present in the proper abstraction you are meant to be using. The general case is "following the conventions" for usage is basically "easier" for people to follow and pick up from when they have some familiarity with MongoDB already.

Comment: Then I will give a try to this library. Maybe I could also get some more performance !